# neo4j basic auth for client http requests

Tags: neo4j

Trying to get adagio with neo4j to run but i dont know how to format login/password in the adagio config file:

```
define(function () {
  'use strict';
    return {
     client: {
        apiEndpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data",
        authBasic:   "Basic neo4j/neo4j",
    },
   },
 }
```

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is right in front of you, not sure though, neo4j is just the default username and password

```
define(function () {
  'use strict';
    return {
     client: {
        apiEndpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data",
        authBasic:   "Basic user/password",
    },
   },
 }
```

Comment: In the original file it looks like:

Comment: authBasic:   "Basic bmVvNGo6ZnJlbmNoZnJvZw==",